# jquery range slider values to query string

Tags: jquery, query-string, uislider

I am using the jQuery UI range slider demo code (http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range) to create a price range slider. I want to transfer the values selected from this range slider to the get params of `minValue` & `maxValue`.

I have been trying to do this by getting the JavaScript to update the hidden fields in the form below but this doesn't seem to work as at the moment the page reloads with the URL query string looking like this: `?minValue=&maxValue=&submit=go` and no values have been transferred from the range slider. How do I get the values from the range slider to the query string?

Thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 1,
        max: 3000,
        values: [ 1, 300 ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( "£" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - £" + ui.values[ 1 ]);
        }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "£" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) + " - £" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
    $( "#minValue" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] );
    $( "#maxValue" ).val( ui.values[ 1 ] );
});
</script>

<form action="">
    <div id="slider-range"></div>
    <label for="amount">Price range:</label><input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#28b1ff; font-weight:bold;" />
    <input id="minValue" name="minValue" type="hidden" />
    <input id="maxValue" name="maxValue" type="hidden" />
    <input id="randomGiftButton" type="submit" name="submit" value="go" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the min/maxValues outside of the slider's code. Move those lines into the `slide` callback function.

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).val( "£" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - £" + ui.values[ 1 ]);
    $( "#minValue" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] );
    $( "#maxValue" ).val( ui.values[ 1 ] );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call the following two lines on `document.ready` the `ui` variable does not exist:

```
$( "#minValue" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] );
$( "#maxValue" ).val( ui.values[ 1 ] );
```

Have you inspected the `ui` variable inside of the `slide` callback function to make sure that you are accessing the data correctly? If you have not yet, then try this and see what comes up in your Developer Tools Console:

```
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log(ui);
        $( "#amount" ).val( "£" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - £" + ui.values[ 1 ]);
    }
```

Also the docs state this is how you access the values:

```
var values = $("#slider-range").slider( "option", "values" );
```

Which returns an array so I assume to access the values you would do this:

```
var min = values[0],
    max = values[1];
```